# Outlook recall email causes exchange email loop

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, exchange-2013

We are currently having an issue where a recalled message when accepted or denied by an internal user causes a loop in Exchange 2013 and prohibits further sending. Exchange track and trace then shows that the recall is trying to send every 5 seconds and the only band-aid fix so far is to migrate the exchange account to another DB.

[Exchange Track and Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQuyI.png)

Has anyone experienced this kind of exchange loop issue and can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Does this happen to one specific user?  After moving account to a new DB, when user recall email again, will issue still occur?

This could also be caused by some client-side aspects. Please try follow steps to see if it works:

1. Open File > Options > Mail.
2. Scroll down to 'Tracking', and set everything to unchecked and "Never...".

(Most specifically, uncheck the items: "Automatically process meeting requests and responses to meeting requests and polls" and "Automatically update original sent item with receipt information")

You may also see [this similar thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/84af8f21-46f4-440d-8c86-e53ab3799837/outlook-2013-message-recall-failure-loop?forum=outlook).

[Message Recall Failure won't stop](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/message-recall-failure-wont-stop/27729456-9e05-4d11-8098-d21c08251169)